# How to pause the sound when use SpriteKit

Tags: objective-c, audio, sprite-kit

I want to use `SpriteKit` to play sound, the question is that I use the function:

```
[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"sound.wav" waitForCompletion:NO];
```

But when I want to pause the game, the sound is still play.

How to stop the sound when `skview.pause` is set to `YES`, and to resume the sound when `skview.pause` is set to `NO`?

Comment: If I'm not wrong you should use the playSoundFileNamed method for playing sound effects... something short 1 or 2 seconds, like explosion sound

Comment: And also I think it would be better if you use AVAudioPlayer for background music, check this tutorial on raywenderlich.com(http://www.raywenderlich.com/49625/sprite-kit-tutorial-space-shooter) see the sound section

Comment: you could also use an audio engine like ObjectAL

Comment: i use the playSoundFileNamed method to play some short sounds, just like explosion,but it should be pause;

Answer (score 9):

Its been some time, but here is the basis of what you can do using AVAudio. I will use background music in this example but it can be done any way. You could put this in a subclass of SKSpriteNode to have a custom sound that can be pause by itself or others.

```
//Add this to your imports:
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>;

//Add the following variable in your interface.
AVAudioPlayer *player;

// Put this in an init or something of the like.
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"musicFileSound" ofType:@"wav"]];
_player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
```

Then to start use `[_player play];`

The use `[_player pause]` to pause.

And `[_player stop]`

[Here is the documentation for it, there are some cool things you can do with it.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html)