# Stopping an SKAction

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, background-music, skaction

I have a sprite kit game with different scenes: the main menu ("MainMenuScene") and the game scene ("MyScene"). While the user is playing the game, I have an endless playing background music. But when the player wants to stop the game and return to main menu, the background music keeps playing. What should I do to make it stop? I have tried `[self removeAllActions]` but it didn't work.

MyScene:

```
    @implementation MyScene
{
    SKAction *_backgroundMusic;
}

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {

        self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.15 green:0.5 blue:0.3 alpha:1.0];
    }
    //Here I make the endless background music 
_backgroundMusic = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"Background 2.m4a" waitForCompletion:YES];
    SKAction * backgroundMusicRepeat = [SKAction repeatActionForever:_backgroundMusic];
    [self runAction:backgroundMusicRepeat];
    return self;
}

- (void)selectNodeForTouch:(CGPoint)touchLocation
{
    SKSpriteNode *touchedNode = (SKSpriteNode *)[self nodeAtPoint:touchLocation];
    if ([_MainMenuButton isEqual:touchedNode]) {
        SKScene *mainMenuScene = [[MainMenuScene alloc]initWithSize:self.size];
        [self.view presentScene:mainMenuScene];
//Here is where the music should stop, when the player presses the 'return to main menu' button
    } 
}
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19754871/how-to-pause-the-sound-when-use-spritekit

Comment: You should really not use ivars here but a strong property. Can you check that the action is not nil before you remove it. I think it might be nil. Just checking though lol!

Comment: No matter what you do, audio initiated by SKAction will not end.

Comment: I mean, not immediately...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend using SKAction to play background music. Instead use AVAudioPlayer.

To use the AVAudioPlayer:

1. Add the AVFoundation to your project.
2. `#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>` into your .m file.
3. Add `AVAudioPlayer *_backgroundMusicPlayer;` in @implementation

Use this code snippet to run your audio:

```
- (void)playBackgroundMusic:(NSString *)filename
{
    NSError *error;
    NSURL *backgroundMusicURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:filename withExtension:nil];
    _backgroundMusicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:backgroundMusicURL error:&error];
    _backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
    _backgroundMusicPlayer.volume = 0.8;
    _backgroundMusicPlayer.delegate = self;
    [_backgroundMusicPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [_backgroundMusicPlayer play];
}
```

Also read up on the [AVAudioPlayer Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Chapters/Reference.html) so you know what all the properties do such as setting volume, number of loops, etc...

Answer (score 0):

try this to play the music:

```
  [self runAction:backgroundMusicRepeat withKey:@"bgmusic"];
```

and this to stop:

```
  [self removeActionForKey:@"bgmusic"];
```

**update**

```
SKAction * backgroundMusicRepeat = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"Background 2.m4a" waitForCompletion:YES];
backgroundMusicRepeat = [SKAction repeatActionForever:backgroundMusicRepeat];

 [self runAction:backgroundMusicRepeat];
```

I have run those code in my own project and seems work.
but not your way, it only stop when I quit the view, I don't even need `removeActionForKey` . `[self removeActionForKey:@"bgmusic"];` won't work in the scene.

So if you want stop sound while switch between diferent scenes of same view, I suggest you using AVAudioPlayer.

I also found some other questions in stackoverflow has the same problem as you, like this:
[how to pause the sound when use SpriteKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19754871/how-to-pause-the-sound-when-use-spritekit)
and this:
[Spritekit stopping sound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22431049/spritekit-stopping-sound)
they both go for the  AVAudioPlayer.

as one of the comment in those links said: ***you should use the playSoundFileNamed method for playing sound effects... something short 1 or 2 seconds, like explosion sound*** --don't use it for background sound.