# SpriteKit: Getting Audio to stop playing

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, sprite-kit

I have code in my Objective-C SpriteKit game to loop a menu theme, but I don't quite know how to get it to stop looping. Here's what I'm using:

```
[self runAction:[SKAction sequence:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"Main Menu Warmup 1.m4a" waitForCompletion:YES], [SKAction runBlock:^{
    [self manageMusic];
}], nil]]];
```

That loops the music just fine, but if I try to call `[self removeAllActions]` to stop the music later, then the music continues playing. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been addressed in the below url. 
[how to pause the sound when use SpriteKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19754871/how-to-pause-the-sound-when-use-spritekit)

*It is mentioned as follows, there is the basis of what you can do using AVAudio. I will use background music in this example but it can be done any way. You could put this in a subclass of SKSpriteNode to have a custom sound that can be pause by itself or others.*